# Javascript: How to make an array that holds 4 objects with the same properties

Tags: javascript

How do I make an array that holds 4 objects with the same properties,  save the objects each to their own variable, then put them all into an array with it’s own variable, then loop through and console log out each person’s name?

Comment: Have you tried something? This is pretty basic stuff

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = { name: 'Jim' };
var b = { name: 'Jane' };
var c = { name: 'Jill' };
var d = { name: 'Joe' };
var list = [a, b, c, d];
list.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.name);
});
```